# Internet speed in the united states

Tags: data-request, internet

I am trying to find geolocated internet speed data. What data sources are available?

I've found:

- [FCC data](https://www.fcc.gov/general/broadband-deployment-data-fcc-form-477): problematic because it's provided by ISPs.
- [Measurement Lab](https://www.measurementlab.net/data/): Open source testing by measurement lab but there's some concern about accuracy.

Ultimately, I'd like to use the data to create some metrics on internet speed by geography (city, state, county, zipcode).

Comment: Did you [search the site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+internet+speed)?

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes. None offered the granular data I needed.